# Reading 0x1a Unicode in R using read.csv

Tags: r

I have a CSV file that I read with `read.csv` in R. Unfortunately, I cannot use anything other than the base R package.

I get the following error:

```
Warning message:
In scan(file = file, what = what, sep = sep, quote = quote, dec = dec,  :
  EOF within quoted string
```

The character where it chokes is `0x1a`(https://numbermonk.com/hexadecimal/26/en). I tried the following as argument in `read.csv`:

- `encoding="UTF-8"`
- `fileEncoding="UTF-8"`
- `quote="`

But I always have that same error. The result is that `read.csv` only reads the rows until it fails.

Here's the example of where this happens:

```
as of 0430 10<0x1a>9-18 shaft on this happens
```

Any ideas on how to make R read this character?

I must add that when I read it in `fread` everything is read just fine. But unfortunately, I cannot use `fread` as it is not part of the base R.

Comment: Can you include the top few rows of the file? Or least a sampling of the columns?

Comment: The error occurs right at the example I have up there. The column is a comments column so any free text can be added a few rows above and after. When I remove those characters, read.csv reads everything correctly.